# How to create Firebase Authentication custom token without service account json in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I want to create a custom token without using a service account json.
Tried the below config items:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#using_a_service_account_id

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#letting_the_admin_sdk_discover_a_service_account

and used the below code to generate a token

```
admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid)
  .then(function(customToken) {
    // Send token back to client
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error creating custom token:', error);
  });
```

Getting the below error :

'Failed to determine service account. Make sure to initialize the SDK with a service account credential. Alternatively specify a service account with iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob permission. Original error: Error: Error while making request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata metadata:80. Error code: ENOTFOUND'

Used the latest "firebase-admin" npm module.

Kindly advice.

Comment: Unless your code is running in a Google managed environment (Cloud Function, etc) the only way you can use is the service account JSON file.

Answer (score 6):

If your code is not running in a managed runtime in Google Cloud, you must either provide a service account JSON file or at very least the `serviceAccountId` app option.

```
admin.initializeApp({
  serviceAccountId: 'my-client-id@my-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
});
```

Comment: what npm module and version to use this?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. By using the `serviceAccountId` during initialization, the SDK will impersonate the service account provided. Make sure the user running the application does have permission to use and create tokens for the service account mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

## 2022 Answer

In the latest `firebase-admin` version, simply providing `serviceAccountId` won't work. You also need to specify `projectId`:

```js
admin.initializeApp({
  projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
  serviceAccountId: process.env.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID,
})
```

If you don't, you will get the following error:

```js
  errorInfo: {
    code: 'app/invalid-credential',
    message: 'Failed to determine project ID: Error while making request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal. Error code: ENOTFOUND'
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize admin by passing your service account key(Download it from Firebase) to credential first. Use this code before calling admin.auth().

```
var serviceAccount = require('./ServiceAccountKey.json')

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});
```

Comment: My question is WITHOUT service account key

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You cannot, the sdk key is the only way to authenticate and authorize your app in order to grant permissions.

Long (not that long) answer: use a cloud function, if it is into your project, it will init it for you, so you don't have to use the key to instantiate the sdk